# C - overcoming the use of atomic operations

Tags: c, atomic

I was wondering. If I have an int variable which I want to be synced across all my threads - wouldn't I be able to reserve one bit to know whether the value is being updated or not?
To avoid the write operation being executed in chunks, which would mean threads could potentially be accessing mid-written value, which is not correct, or even worse, overwrite it, causing it to be totally wrong, I want the threads to first be informed that the variable is being written to. I could simply use an atomic operation to write the new value so that the other threads don't interfere, but this idea does not seem that dumb and I would like to use the basic tools first.
What if I just make one operation, which is small enough to keep it in one chunk, an operation like changing a single bit (which will still result in the whole byte(s) changing, but it's not the whole value changing, right), and let the bit indicate the variable is being written to or not? Would that even work, or would the whole int be written to?
I mean, even if the whole int was to change, this still would have a chance of working - if the bit indicating if the value is changing was written first.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT: I feel like I did not specify what I am actually planning to do, and why I thought of this in the first place.
I am trying to implement a timeout function, similarly to setTimeout in JavaScript. It is pretty straightforward for a timeout that you don't want to ever cancel - you create a new thread, tell it to sleep for given amount of time, then give it a function to execute, eventually with some data. Piece of cake. Finished writing it in maybe half an hour, while being totally new to C.
The hard part comes when you want to set a timeout which might be canceled in the future. So you do exactly the same as a timeout without canceling, but when the thread wakes up and the CPU's scheduler puts it on, the thread must check if a value in the memory it was given when it started does not say 'you should stop executing'. The value could potentially be modified by other thread, but it would only be done once, at least in the best case scenario. I will worry about different solutions when it comes down to trying to modify the value from multiple threads at the same time. The base assumption right now is that only the main thread, or one of other threads, can modify the value, and it will happen only once. Control of it happening only once can be by setting up other variable, which might change multiple times, but always to the same value (that is, initial value is 0 and it means not-yet-canceled, but then when it must be canceled, the value changes to 1, so there is no worrying about the value being fragmented into multiple write operations and only chunk of it being updated at the time of reading it by different thread).
Given this assumption, I think the text I initially wrote at the beginning of this post should be more clear. In a nutshell, no need to worry about the value being written multiple times, only once, but by any thread, and the value must be available to be read by any other thread, or it must be indicated that it cannot be read.
Now as I am thinking of it, since the value itself will only ever be 0 or 1, the trick with knowing when it's already been canceled should work too, shouldn't it? Since the 0 or 1 will always be in one operation, so there is no need to worry about it being fragmented and read incorrectly. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
On the other hand, what if the value is being written from the end, not the beginning? If it's not possible then no need to worry and the post will be resolved, but I would like to know of every danger that might come with overcoming atomic operations like this, in this specific context. In case it is being written from the end, and a thread wants to access the variable to know if it should continue executing, it will notice that it indeed should, while the expected behaviour would be to stop executing. This should have completely minimal chance of being possible, but still is, which means it is dangerous, and I want it to be 100% predictable.

Another edit to explain what steps I imagine the program to make.
Main thread spawns a new thread, aka 'cancelable timeout'. It passes a function to execute along with data, time to sleep, and memory address, pointing to a value. After the thread wakes up after given time, it must check the value to see if it should execute the function it has been given. 0 means it should continue, 1 means it should stop and exit. The value (thread's 'state', canceled or not canceled) can be manipulated by either the main thread, or any other thread, 'timeout', which's job is to cancel the first thread.
Sample code:

```
struct Timeout {
  void (*function)(void* data);
  void* data;
  int milliseconds;
  int** base;
  int cancelID;
};
DWORD WINAPI CTimeout(const struct Timeout* data) {
  Sleep(data->milliseconds);
  if(*(*(data->base) + sizeof(int) * data->cancelID) == 0) {
    data->function(data->data);
  }
  free(data);
  return 0;
}
```

Where CTimeout is a function provided to the newly-spawned thread. Please note that I have written some of this code on go and haven't tested it. Ignore any potential errors.
Timeout.base is pointer to a pointer to an array of ints, since many timeouts can exists at the same time. Timeout.cancelID is the ID of current thread on the list of timeouts. The same ID has a value if treated as index in the base array. If the value is 0, the thread should execute its function, else, clean up the data it has been given and nicely return.  The reason behind base being pointer to a pointer, is because at any time, the array of states of timeouts can be resized. In case place of the array changes, there is no option to pass its initial place. It might potentially cause a segmentation fault (if not, correct me please), for accessing memory which does not belong to us anymore.
Base can be accessed from the main thread or other threads if necessary, and the state of our thread can be changed to cancel its execution.
If any thread wants to change the state (the state as state of the timeout we spawned at the beginning and want to cancel), it should change the value in the 'base' array. I think this is pretty straightforward so far.
There would be a huge problem if the values for continuing and stopping would be something bigger than just 1 byte. Operation to write to the memory could actually take multiple operations, and thus, accessing the memory too early would cause unexpected results to occur, which is not what I am fond of. Though, as I earlier mentioned out, what if the value is very small, 0 or 1? Wouldn't it matter at all at what time the value is accessed at? We are interested only in 1 byte, or even 2 or 4 bytes or the whole number, even 8 bytes wouldn't make any difference in this case, would they? In the end, there is no worry about receiving an invalid value, since we don't care about 32bit value, but just 1 bit, no matter how many bytes we would be reading.
Maybe it isn't exactly understandable what I mean. Write/read operations do not consist of reading single bits, but byte(s). That is, if our value is not bigger than 255, or 65535, or 4 million million, whatever the amount of bytes we are writing/reading is, we shouldn't worry about reading it in middle of it being written. What we care about is only one chunk of what is being written, the last or the first byte(s). The rest is completely useless to us, so no need to worry about it all being synced at the time we access the value. The real problem starts when the value is being written to, but the first byte written to is at the end, which is useless to us. If we read the value at that moment, we will receive what we shouldn't - no cancel state instead of cancel. If the first byte, given little endian, was to be read first, we would receive valid value even if reading in the middle of write.
Perhaps I am mangling and mistaking everything. I am not a pro, you know. Perhaps I have been reading trashy articles, whatever. If I am wrong about anything at all, please correct me.

Comment: Don't try to build your own syncing mechanisms.  Use a mutex.

Comment: you ask two different questions. one is about the atomicity. another one is about thread safety. @dbush gave you the best advice.

Comment: You could try to implement the bakery algorthm. If you are adventurous...

Comment: @wildplasser very interesting algorithm, thanks for suggesting it! i will consider implementing it.

Comment: The custemers **must** be numbered (1..N), and **must** know their own number, IIRC.

Comment: You seem to have some idea what an atomic operation is, so have you considered using C-standard or your compiler's specific mechanisms for *bona fide* atomic data types and / or operations?  C has had (optional) standard support for atomics since C11. Or since you appear to be on Windows and using MSVC (my condolences), you could consider [Microsoft's custom atomic-operation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#interlocked-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Except for some specialised embedded environments with dedicated hardware, there is no such thing as "one operation, which is small enough to keep it in one chunk, an operation like changing a single bit". You need to keep in mind that you do not want to simply overwrite the special bit with "1" (or "0"). Because even if you could do that, it might just coincide with some other thread doing the same. What you need in fact to do is to check whrther it is already 1 and ONLY if it is NOT write a 1 yourself and KNOW that you did not overwrite an existing 1 (or that writing your 1 failed because of a 1 already being there).

This is called the critical section. And this problem can only be solved by the OS, which happens to know or be able to prevent about other parallel threads. This is the reason for the existence of the OS-supported synchronisation methods.

There is no easy way around this.

Comment: Your comment is very good, but does not regard what I really meant. I have edited the post because of that to clarify the context of my question a little more. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I think your edit does not change anything. As long as the variable is potentially written by more than one thread, even if in total only by one thread, each thread does not know whether another one has written before. Maybe you can describe the chronological sequence of what happens. Make sure to cover the knowledge of each thread (e.g. "thread A wants to write, but first needs to find out whether thread B already has written"). I think that if you do that cleanly, you will see that your idea does not work. If you can do it so that it seems to work I will do my best to find and highlight gap.

Comment: Main thread decides to set a cancelable timeout. A new thread spawns, it goes to sleep for, let's say, 1 second. When it wakes up, it must check a value at memory address it was given. 0 means continue, 1 means stop executing. The main thread, and potentially a different thread which was spawned to cancel the first thread, can manipulate the value. They could possibly change it to 1, and even if it happened multiple times, as long as it happens by writing the least significant byte(s) first, not the last (given little endian), the cancelable timeout should know about it instantly. Right?

Comment: Could possibly just stop the thread from executing, that's another way which I haven't thought of before, but then, what if the timeout is canceled way too late, and the function we wanted to execute is already executing? exiting the thread would cause the function to perhaps not finish what it wanted to do, leading to unexpected results. The only acceptable way seems to sync the cancel value somehow.

Comment: Please use the space and formatting features offered by editing that into the question. I recommend numbered list of steps. So that referenceing the problematic step will be convenient. Try to play through all possible combinations of which thread reads/writes when. In my experience it pays to consider the "other" thread a nasty lurker which intentionally waits for the exactly worst moment to do its part, with perfect nanosecond timing if necessary. I.e. try to break your idea, not try to describe how it works.

Comment: Yes, I do try to break it, but I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge to think of every possibility. That is where stackoverflow comes into play, a place where I can ask more experienced people, with more knowledge.